# Bluetooth Headset Audio Mapped to Microphone?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headset

I have an issue where audio recorded from my Bluetooth Headset seems blown out, "sounds like a vacuum cleaner" and echo-y. It doesn't hit pitch feedback but the wave forms are much longer than the test "pop" sound and they seem to echo as they fade away.

What works:

- Hodeadset connects well
- Audio works fine under A2DB, sounds great
- Switching to HSP/HFP mode seems fine - sound quality degrades but Pulse shows the microphone now

What is strange:

- `pavucontrol` shows "Monitor of QC35" as well as "QC35" in the Input Devices section. The non monitor one seems to have a very high indicator/wave form for the little amount of noise currently.
- Changing that slider, even down to 0% has no effect, the bouncing output volume indicator is still really high, bouncing off the top
- Any change I make in `alsamixer` seems to do nothing.

Maybe it's just an issue with recording volume?

#### Environment

```
$ uname -a
Linux seth-mini-box 5.3.0-51-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 22 21:09:44 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=19.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=eoan
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 19.10"
```

```
$ pulseaudio --version
pulseaudio 13.0
```

Possibly related to this? https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/issues/776